# JVM Tomcat Liferay: Code Cache at 95% in production

Tags: jvm, liferay, tomcat7, jvm-arguments

Using JVM 1.7.0_51 and Tomcat 7 and Liferay Portal CE 6.2GA3 I'm seeing that in JVM's Metrics the value of Code Cache is 95%

In no Tomcat and/or Liferay tuning guide I found the management and/or advice about Code Cache related parameters.

Please anyone could address my to understand this issue ?

Thank you in advance,
Ivano C.

Comment: are you actually experiencing any problems?

Comment: After 10-12 hours the Code Cache value is normalized around 40-50%.  Waiting to see after the next restart of the server if it is a normal process